# How to exit "->" in macOS terminal for mysql?

Tags: mysql-cli

I was testing commands like "status" for mysql, then I suddenly entered this mode I don't recognize. Can not do anything from here. Whatever I entered, it's just roll into next line.[image]

Comment: You can enter `\c` as stated in the output above the input prompt to clear the current input.

Comment: The `[` at the start of the line indicates that you used a `[` in a command. That command should be closed, which can be done with a `;` .   After this `\h` gives help, or `\q` quits.

Answer (score 1):

use `exit` or `quit` and also `\q`to leave the mysql shell

see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html)

To get to the next command you can use ; semicolon like you end all sql comands

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete each command with a semicolon. So just type a semicolon and return and your command will be executed